# Bash while loop issue with output

Tags: bash, expect

I have an issue I'm looking for help with relating to a monitoring script I'm building.

There are two components, 1) the bash script which performs the logic and 2) and expect script which connects to various hosts via SSH, runs a command and pulls back the result into the bash script as a multi-line variable for further manipulation.

The issue I have is that I need to add text around each line of the result, but this is proving far more difficult that expected!

```
printf %s "$EXPECT_RESULT" | while IFS= read -r line
     do
        echo "$line" text
done
}
```

The result of the small test above is not as expected:

```
line1_content txt
line2_content txt
line3_content txt
```

Instead the result is:

```
txte1_content
txte1_content
txte1_content
```

The "txt" is added at the begining of the line and overwrites part of the output I'm after.

If I manually produce the $EXPECT_RESULT as a multi-line variable, it behaves as expected so the issue definitely seems related the output coming from expect.

Any idea or gotchas I'm not aware of?

Thanks!

Comment: Your variable probably contains `\r` characters

Comment: Mat, you were right, thank you so much.  For anyone else's benefit, I used the bash program "od" to show all characters and then "tr" to remove the \r characters.  All working now!

Answer (score 0):

Mat, you were right, thank you so much. For anyone else's benefit, I used the bash program "od" to show all characters and then "tr" to remove the \r characters. All working now!